# (Javascript) CSS width() property not applied until window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple scrubber for playing music, using two divs, $scrubber and $progress, and increasing the width of the progress as the song progresses.

```
<div class="a-meter" id="scrubber" aria-label="60%" style="height:5px">
    <div class="a-meter-bar" id="progress">
    </div>
</div>
```

As I receive progress events, I calculate the width and then use Javascript to set $progress' width property.

```
    countdownTimeout = setTimeout(updateCountdown, 100);
    var x = (interval)*(durationSeconds-secondsRemaining)+"%";
    console.log("width is "+x);
    $progress.width((interval)*(durationSeconds-secondsRemaining)+"%");
```

I can see these log statements as the song progresses and the % increases. **However, the progress bar width will not actually be set until the window is resized.**

It does not matter in which direction or how small of a change I make, it immediately kicks in the width and the progress bar races to catch up.

This only happens in Chrome, and only recently started without much code change to this file - Firefox works as expected and the width is set normally.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong or how I might fix it? Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: added JSFiddle with basic idea of what the expected behavior is: https://jsfiddle.net/ympu6rt3/3/

Comment: does it make a difference if you use `$progress.css("width", "...")` instead of `.width()`?

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @mkaminsky I've tried both with no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: @box86rowh, I just added one to OP: https://jsfiddle.net/ympu6rt3/

Comment: You mention that this works fine in Firefox (have you tested IE as well?) Is your Chrome up to date? Seems like a machine problem to me, as the code looks fine. (Side note: why not use `x` in the `.width()`?)

Comment: @TurdPile I haven't had a chance to test on IE yet, but I suspect you are right. I'm just unsure as to why it stopped working now when no code related to this module has been changed - I just integrated with another package and somehow it does not work until resize now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A: Let me know when you've tested with IE. B: You say the JSFiddle example works perfectly fine in your Chrome? C: Are you testing this yourself via the code you posted to this question? The issue might lie elsewhere in code you didn't actually provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem is that you call wrong to the element from jquery **$progress** it should be **$('#progress')**, also use setInterval instead of setTimeOut due to setTimeOut is executed only one time, while setInterval run the function constantly.

```
countdownTimeout = setInterval(updateCountdown(), 100);
function updateCountdown(){
    var x = (interval)*(durationSeconds-secondsRemaining)+"%";
    console.log("width is "+x);
    $('#progress').width((interval)*(durationSeconds-secondsRemaining)+"%");
}
```

Comment: It is already assumed, based on the original posting, that `$progress = $('#progress');` which is pretty much confirmed since the OP says it works in Firefox perfectly fine.